# What is the difference between 试验 and 实验?

Tags: synonyms, nuance

Both 试验 and 实验 seems to be translated into "experiment". What is the difference between the two words? Can they be used interchangeably or not?

Comment: I thought you were native Chinese born and raised near Beijing? On Baidu there are many pages explaining the difference.

Comment: Anyone can propose a question here even he knows the answer already, as long as the question can benefit the community. This site is a little quiet now and I think more such questions are welcomed,at least in my opinion.

Comment: Well said, Huang!

Comment: @BertR  I am a native. But one day I came cross this I had to reference a dictionary. So I think this would benefit the learners also.

Comment: Me too, I mess up these two since I was in 珊瑚實驗小學 and later 某中學實驗班

Answer (score 8, accepted):

实验 is used for operations and activities done to test a scientific theory or hypothesis. An example: 经过反复实验，证明这一结论是正确的

试验 is used to inspect the function or effect of some physical thing (something that already exists). It's typically done in some lab.
Some examples:

- 新农药要经过反复试验才能推广
- 试验新机器
- 新办法试验后推广

Answer (score 3):

Simply put:

实验 - An experiment

试验 - A trial

Comment: butwho, Welcome to Chinese SE. As the note below says, when providing an answer, please try to provide context/reasoning behind *why* you've answered as you have. Otherwise, you can leave a comment. Thanks